# How can I mongoimport with Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoimport

I made a mongoexport of some local data that I now want to mongoimport into production. I'm trying the following command:

```
mongoimport -h production-db-b2.meteor.io --port 27017 --username client --password password_that_expires_fast --collection collection_name --db prod_meteor_com --file ./mongo_import.json
```

This appears to be quite similar to the solution posted here: [how to mongoimport data to deployed meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369034/how-to-mongoimport-data-to-deployed-meteor-app)

However, it's not working with the error `couldn't connect to [production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017] couldn't connect to server production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017`

How do I get around this?

(Note: I also tried concatenating the port and host into `-h production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017` to no avail)

Comment: I ran into this exact issue and was planning to write a short blog post about how I get around it because it was a huge pain in the rear, I'll try to get an answer for you up soon. I know I used mongodump and mongorestore instead of import/export for one, but that's not your only problem.

Comment: try this: mongoimport -u client -h production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017 -d myapp_meteor_com -p passwordthatexpiresreallyfast /pathtofile

Comment: Hey that worked. Thanks Spencer. You want to post it below and I'll give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the past. I'm not exactly sure of why it works and your solution doesn't, but I think it has something to do with not specifying the collection or the file in a certain way.

```
mongoimport -u client -h production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017 -d myapp_meteor_com -p passwordthatexpiresreallyfast /pathtofile
```

Answer (score 1):

check your port. the local meteor mongodb uses 3001 not 27017...

i'm using the following line successfully

mongoimport --host localhost:3001  -d meteor -c TestCollection --type csv --file /home/ubuntu/meteorMongoImportTest/results1.txt --headerline