# Deploy local mongo collection to meteor.com server

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I am starting my first meteor app, using MongoDB for my database.

I have copied my data in from a JSON file into mongodb collection and when hosting locally, the data appears as expected; the collection is in the meteor mongo database and I can interpret at will

When I deploy the app to xx.meteor.com, the meteor collection I need (named 'assets') does not get posted to the mongodb on the server. I can check this by using `meteor mongo onemore.meteor.com`. Other collections are posted though.

How do I deploy my mongoDB colletion ('assets') along with the app using `meteor deploy`?

Is this issue due to the way the mongodatabase was orginally imported? I used this method: https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/database-management.md

I copied the collection ('assets) from a staging database using `db.copyDatabase('staging3','meteor','localhost')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using mongodump and mongorestore also works:

1. Dump data from existing mongodb (mongodb url: mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@DBHOST/DBNAME)

   ```
   mongodump -h DBHOST -d DBNAME -u USER -p PASSWORD
   ```

   This will create a "dump" directory, with all the data going to dump/DBNAME.
2. Get the mongodb url for the deployed meteor app (i.e. www.mymeteorapp.com)

   ```
   meteor mongo --url METEOR_APP_URL
   ```

   This will return the following:

   ```
   mongodb://#USERNAME#:#PASSWORD#@#HOSTNAMEANDPORT#/#YOURAPPLICATION#
   ```

   Note: the PASSWORD expires every min.
3. Upload the db dump data to the meteor app (using an example meteor db url)

   ```
   mongorestore -u #USERNAME# -p #PASSWORD# -h #HOSTNAMEANDPORT# -d www_mymeteorapp_com dump/DBNAME/
   ```

   All the data should get transferred!

This answer is basically a modified version of [Davidd8's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874806/1660118), but because that was never accepted I reposted it here.

Comment: Just to mention that when I performed `mongorestore` I had to use `-d www_mymeteorapp_com dump/DBNAME/` as using `-db` threw an error.  Other than then, this is a great solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me. Here is what did the trick for me:

1) How do I get my localhost dump of my meteor db?
tip 1: make sure mongo is running (type mongod to run it)
Which port was my meteor running on?
    $ mongodump --host localhost:3002 (nope)
    $ mongodump --host localhost:3000 (nope)
    $ mongodump --host localhost:3001 (yes!) this worked

Now where the heck did it put my dump?
    $ ls (shows me the dump is in my current directory and meteor is inside the dump directory)

I need to somehow get that meteor data onto my live site on meteor.com

Now the next problem is that meteor.com will give me the information I need but I only have 1 minute before their information expires.

This information is what I need to connect to my remote meteor site and import my local meteor data.

I type this in the terminal:
    $ meteor mongo --url iamcool.meteor.com

Then it spits back something like this:

```
mongodb://client-11f3014w:f1c52f68-8506-b682-c880-b5db03a9510e@production-db-a2.meteor.io:27017/iamcool_meteor_com
```

I used info from above that told me what data to extract from the above code and where to put it in the mongorestore code

```
mongorestore -u #USERNAME# -p #PASSWORD# -h #HOSTNAMEANDPORT# -db www_mymeteorapp_com dump/DBNAME/
```

This is where you have to be a super fast typer. I recommend opening a blank file in your IDE (Sublime Text or Atom or whatever you use) and create this template:

```
mongorestore -u XXX -p XXX -h production-db-a2.meteor.io:27017 -db iamcool_meteor_com dump/meteor
```

So I took the data meteor.com gave me and I plugged it in below:

```
mongorestore -u client-4bf9be36 -p d1cdef86-6c71-3b11-ef4c-221fbdcf07d0 -h production-db-a2.meteor.io:27017 -db iamcool_meteor_com dump/meteor
```

And then the errors came. And boy did they come.

Sometimes I got this error:
too many positional arguments

Sometimes I got this error:
Failed: error connecting to db server: auth fails

But this error tip gave me the info that saved the day:
    try 'mongorestore --help' for more information

I did and I found out that the flag to pass for database wasn't -db but rather -d

I made the following change and typed it fast using my trusty template (see above)

mongorestore -u client-4bf9be36 -p d1cdef86-6c71-3b11-ef4c-221fbdcf07d0 -h production-db-a2.meteor.io:27017 -d iamcool_meteor_com dump/meteor

And then it worked.

It took me two hours to figure out. Hope it saves you the time I lost.

Comment: This is THE solution. I'd have cut it short though, and get straight to the point, but still sorted me out. Thx @Pip !