# Meteor deploy to myapp.meteor.com not displaying changes seen on localhost

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Using Telescope app and everything is running great on my localhost. I was able to play with the settings, create an account and get the app started.

I deployed it to appname.meteor.com, but it's only showing the original Telescope app, without my changes I can see on localhost.

Deploys look fine, but the changes aren't reflected on appname.meteor.com

```
$ meteor deploy appname.meteor.com
$ Deploying to appname.meteor.com. Bundling...
$ Uploading...
$ Now serving at appname.meteor.com
```

New to all this - any help is appreciated!

Comment: What kinds of changes? If you made changes to the code before deploying then you should see those changes on the deployed app. If however you mean stuff like making an account and changing settings within the telescope webapp itself all of those are changes that happen to the mongodb database which doesn't get uploaded when you deploy. Also code changes made after you deploy have to be redeployed before you will see them on appname.meteor.com

Comment: Cool-thanks. And yeah, it's just the data from mongodb. I'm not seeing the account I created, or the first post I made. I'll look into it, but do you have any recommendations on how to connect/upload this? --update-- think i found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369034/how-to-mongoimport-data-to-deployed-meteor-app)

Comment: nvm -- still seeing error messages when i try $meteor mongo 
mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.

This command only works while Meteor is running your application
locally. Start your application first. (This error will also occur if
you asked Meteor to use a different MongoDB server with $MONGO_URL when
you ran your application.)

If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed
with 'meteor deploy', specify your site's name with this command.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to deploy your development mongodb to meteor.com.

You can achieve this by using the following script:

```
# How to upload local db to meteor:

# -h = host, -d = database name, -o = dump folder name
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3002 -d meteor -o meteor

# get meteor db url, username, and password
meteor mongo --url myapp.meteor.com

# -h = host, -d = database name (app domain), -p = password, folder = the path to the  dumped db
mongorestore -u client -h c0.meteor.m0.mongolayer.com:27017 -d myapp_meteor_com -p 'password' folder/
```

Make sure your application is running or the mongodump will fail

[Source for script](https://gist.github.com/IslamMagdy/5519514)

Answer (score 0):

Dump files should be located in /dump/meteor instead of simply /dump.