# How-to import meteor.js db to remote mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an app developed using meteor.js; since locally it is ok, I would like now to move it to my dedicated server;
I've installed mongodb 2.6 on the server following official doc;
I've made a dump of my local app's db by using:

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

and uploaded the dump folder to /var/www/mywebsite on my server;

mongodb is configured to use auth: true;

trying

```
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 -d mydbname dump/meteor
```

nothing is inserted (using mongo shell as root, the only databases I can see are local and admin)

my root mongodb user is created on admin db:
(i've tried also):

```
mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --username root --password xxxxxx -d mydbname dump/meteor

{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to have a mongo user for the new database and restore it;
after trying some different things I realized I'm not understanding how to do... Somebody can help with this?

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874806/956779) to *[how to mongoimport data to deployed meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369034/how-to-mongoimport-data-to-deployed-meteor-app)* :

1. Dump data from existing mongodb (mongodb url: mongodb://USER:PASSWORD@DBHOST/DBNAME)

   ```
   mongodump -h DBHOST -d DBNAME -u USER -p PASSWORD
   ```

   This will create a "dump" directory, with all the data going to dump/DBNAME.
2. Get the mongodb url for the deployed meteor app (i.e. www.mymeteorapp.com)

   ```
   meteor mongo --url METEOR_APP_URL
   ```

   Note: the PASSWORD expires every min.
3. Upload the db dump data to the meteor app (using an example meteor db url)

   ```
   mongorestore -u MY_REMOTE_DATABASE_USERNAME -p MY_REMOTE_DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD -h production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017 -db www_mymeteorapp_com dump/DBNAME/
   ```

   All the data should get transferred!